# Custom checkbox not updating the real checkbox value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i'm trying to make a simple custom checkbox with jQuery ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/ST32J/)).

I don't understand why it doesn't check / uncheck the real checkboxes. Ids selectors are passed correctly, so is the realtime value.

Relevant html:

```
<div id="corpo">
<div id="checkoptions">
<div><label>Option 1 <input type="checkbox" id="option1" checked></label></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Relevant javascript:

```
// custom checkboxes
$('#corpo input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){

    var checkbox = $(this), checkid = checkbox.attr('id'),
            checked =  '', content = '&#10007;';

    if(checkbox.is(':checked')){ var checked =  ' checked', content = '&#10003;'; }

    checkbox.hide()
            .after('<div class="checkbox'+checked+'" id="c-'+checkid+'"><span>'+content+'</span></div>');
});

// update custom checkboxes values
$('#corpo').on('click','.checkbox',function(){

    var fakeCheckbox = $(this),
            realID = fakeCheckbox.attr('id').replace('c-',''),
            realCheckbox = $('#'+realID), checked = realCheckbox.is(':checked');

    if(checked){

        realCheckbox.attr('checked',false);
        fakeCheckbox.removeClass('checked').find('span').html('&#10007;');

    }else{

        realCheckbox.attr('checked',true);
        fakeCheckbox.addClass('checked').find('span').html('&#10003;');

    }

});
```

I've already tried to unhide original checkboxes, to use `prop('checked',false)` and `removeAttr('checked')` instead of `attr('checked',false)`.

I need to update the real checkboxes too, switching class in the "fake" checkbox isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#corpo').on('click','.checkbox',function(e){
    var isChecked = $(this).is('.checked');
    $(this).html(isChecked ? '&#10007;' : '&#10003;').toggleClass('checked');
    $('#'+this.id.replace('c-','')).prop('checked', !isChecked);

  //solve the annoying select issue
    document.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
    e.target.ondragstart = function() { return false; };
    return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ST32J/7/)

Comment: Wooow thanks a lot, it works! what's `ondragstart` and `onselectstart` ?

Comment: nevermind, just read your edit! anyway, what's the difference with my code? (except yours is well-written i mean)

Comment: Mine just toggles the state in a simple way, it does'nt jump thru a lot of hoops to do so. And yes, the last three lines solves the issue with selecting the text (turning blue) when clicking in certain browsers. Also be aware that the markup does'nt change in Chrome Inspector etc. the checkbox will still have the checked attribute, but it really is unchecked, and will be so if a form is submitted etc.

Comment: The selecting text workaround is awesome! Me grateful :) anyway, i actually need those hoops (more stuff happens if is un/checked). I don't get why  `$('#'+this.id.replace('c-','')).prop('checked', !isChecked);` works while mine not

Comment: Oh really, it doesn't toggle the actual checkbox state? ... is it 'cause they're hidden, or there's no way to do it?

Comment: well, no! The real checkbox is of course toggled. What I was saying is that if you look at the html in for instance something like chrome's html inspector, the checkbox will always have the checked attribute, but in reality it is unchecked, here's a quick test : http://jsfiddle.net/ST32J/9/

Answer (score 1):

You had problems with `is(':checked')`, changing your code and removing ID detection:

```
// update custom checkboxes values
$('#corpo .checkbox').on('click',function(){
    var fakeCheckbox = $(this),
        realCheckbox = $(this).siblings('input'),
    checked = fakeCheckbox.hasClass('checked');
    if(checked){
        fakeCheckbox.removeClass('checked').find('span').html('&#10007;');
        realCheckbox.removeAttr('checked');
    }else{
        fakeCheckbox.addClass('checked').find('span').html('&#10003;');
        realCheckbox.attr('checked','checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the `siblings` hint!